# What's the difference between a user group and query group in AWS Redshift Workload Management?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, workload

I'm struggling to understand what the difference is between a ***user group*** and a ***query group*** when manually implementing query queues in AWS Redshift. What is the difference in implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are 2 properties that can be used in deciding query placement into a queue.  One, user group, has lots of meaning within Redshift like assigning user privileges and can only be changed by an admin as it is a database-wide configuration.  The other, query group, is a user settable (session) property that isn't overloaded with additional meaning.  User group = static and global.  Query group = dynamic and connection specific.

These 2 properties are used by the workload manager as inputs when choosing queues for queries.  I have found the graphic on this page to be very helpful in understanding the WLM decision process. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/cm-c-wlm-queue-assignment-rules.html

Comment: Amazing thank you Bill! The above and the graphic you shared have massively helped my understanding.